# Junit for java Clock without any extra class or constructer or Injection

Tags: java, java-8

I have below method

```
public long printDate(ZonedDateTime otherDate){
   LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
   ZonedDateTime now = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
   Duration dur = Duration.between(otherDate, now);
   long seconds = dur.getSeconds();
   return seconds;
}
```

I want to write a Junit for this method but I am not getting how to mock `Clock.fixed(...)` for different times.

is there any way to test above method without using Clock as a method parameter or without initialization in constructor of Clock or without using any extra utility class.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: don't even attempt this. Static access is almost always an impediment to testable code. Don't acquire your `Clock` via a static method. Instead, create your `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` outside of this method, and inject it either as a method parameter, or via constructor/setter injection into this method's class (exactly as you say you don't want to do!)

You can then provide whatever `Clock` you like for your unit tests.

The whole point of the `Clock` class is so you can do this! The whole point is that a `Clock` can be injected, whereas static calls like `new Date()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` can not.

If you absolutely must test code that utilises static methods, Powermock or similar may help with this. In my opinion, apart from in legacy code whose dependencies you can't unpick, this will almost never be necessary.

Comment: Thanks, nice analogy! I don't really get the downvote tbh. The question basically boils down to "how do I test a static method call?". The answer is "use Powermock". The longer answer is "but please don't, and in time you'll thank me for it".